# EditText to String name to different class

Tags: java, android

Having a bit of problem as I would like on my application for the user to enter an IP address and for that IP entry to be used to connect to the other device. In these two classes, the IPEntry class is set up to read the IP through the EditText and get coverts it to a string. I then want it to be passed and used within my ClientUpload class. Obviously I had attempted to already solve this to no avail. When I use it with the following way it says it cannot find the IP so it isn't transferring. I also tried to get in within a method and call upon that but that didn't work either. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

IPEntry Class

```
public class IPEntry extends Activity {

Button Submit;
EditText IP;
TextView Thistext;
public String ipadd;
public Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.ipentry);
  Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIPSubmit);
  Thistext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTextIP);
  IP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edIPBar);   

  Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     ipadd = IP.getText().toString();

           Intent Trans = new Intent("wishift.mat.ANDROIDEXPLORER");
           startActivity(Trans);
                     }              
                     }
  );
}}
```

Relevant Part of Client Upload Class

```
public class ClientUpload extends Thread{

IPEntry ipentry = new IPEntry();

public int UploadFile(File file) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{


  //loop 
  int serverPort = 6880;                  
 //   String ip = "192.168.1.73";
  String ip = ipentry.ipadd;
  Socket socket = new Socket(ip, serverPort);
```

As you can see I commented out the part which does work but I would very much not like to manually add the IP in code.

Comment: _Please post any logcat errors._  Do you actually pass `ipadd` in your Intent bundle?

Comment: try to print the value of ip.i think you are getting null .

Comment: I am getting a null value. No I'm not passing into an Intent bundle. The issue is that the ClientUpload class isn't using anything from Android, it is almost just a java class within the Android project. So obviously I can't use any Android specific methods within this class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `IPEntry` object created here: `IPEntry ipentry = new IPEntry();` in ClientUpload is a ***new*** `IPEntry` object; it does not share the same value of `ipadd`. The default constructor will set it to `null`.

There are many ways to solve this; you can either add a constructor to ClientUpload with a `String` argument for the IP address and save it in an instance variable or add another argument to the uploadFile() method to accept the IP address.

You can also make the `ipadd` varible `static`, allowing it to be accessed across all IPEntry instances, although I do not recommend this as it is completely unnecessary and multiple `IPEntry` objects will require more (unnecessary) memory and overhead.